# Error creating an index on postgresql with desc

Tags: postgresql, indexing

When executing the following on postgresql 8.2:

```
CREATE INDEX product_index_8 ON product (product_id DESC, naam DESC, verbruik_per_eenheid DESC, inhoud DESC, barcode DESC);
```

We get the error:

```
  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DESC"
    LINE 1: ...EATE INDEX product_index_8 ON product (product_id DESC, naam...  
    ********** Error **********   
    ERROR: syntax error at or near "DESC"
    SQL state: 42601
    Character: 53
```

Anyone knows what is going on? we Have the same index on a oracle server and it works without a problem.

Comment: Works here (PG-9.3.3) Maybe you should upgrade to a more recent version, pg-8.2 is EOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, you aren't using PostgreSQL, you're using Greenplum Database or Amazon Redshift.

If you really are using 8.2: [PostgreSQL 8.2 does not support `DESC`ending ordered indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createindex.html).

[Newer versions do](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) - it was added in 8.3, per [the release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-8-3.html) and docs.

Upgrade, [8.2 is obsolete](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Comment: We are useing PostgreSQL, we are looking into an upgrade atm. We found more issues.